# Not able to understand the logic of validation statement where int is added to char array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm working on one un document code. I have a hard time in understanding one logic.

Don't understand this logic. I need to feed in with only 4 bytes, adding int 4 with 3rd indexes of buf, example 4 + 12 = 16 in hex.

This is my buf[256]= "04 02 56 12"

some can explain why this if becomes true?

```
if (n < 4 || 4 + buf[3] != n)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "n is:%d, length byte does not match number of bytes\n", n);
    return;
}
```

What I want is to print I'm sending the data. But the buffer I construct seems it's not valid according to that if validation statement.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static void process(char *s)
{
    uint8_t buf[256];
    unsigned n;
    unsigned long v;
    char *p;

    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    while (isspace(*s))
        s++;
    //sanity check if buf is not empty
    if (!*s) {
        printf("S is empty\n");
        return;
    }


    n = 0;
    while (n < sizeof(buf)) {
        // convert the string into unsigned long int value to given 
        // base accepts only hex
        v = strtoul(s, &p, 16);
        if (p == s || v > 255) {
            fprintf(stderr, "bad data in string for byte %u\n", n);
            return;
        }

        s = p;
        while (isspace(*s))
            s++;

        buf[n++] = v;

        if (!*s)
            break;
    }
    //this just prints the number of whitespaces inbetween the buffer data.
    printf("N %d after while\n", n);
    //printing the buffer   
    int i=0;    
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        printf(" %02x", (int)buf[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    // Dont understand this logic. I need to feed in with only 4 bytes
    // adding int with 3 indexs of buf, example 4 + a = e in hex.
    if (n < 4 || 4 + buf[3] != n)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "n is:%d, length byte does not match number of bytes\n", n);
        return;
    }

    printf("Sending the data\n");
}

int main() {
    char s[256] = "04 02 56 12";
    printf("buf_size:%lu string:%s\n", sizeof(s), s);

    process(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buf[3]` is the character `'0'`, which in [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) have the value `48`. Therefore when you do `4 + buf[3] != n` what you're really doing is `4 + 48 != n` or `52 != n`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out "04 02 56 12" buf[3] is 0. I don't the reason why int 4 is added only to buf[3] ? maybe its something to with length of the buffer?

Comment: Should add that `4 + '0' == '4'` (always; `'0'`-`'9'` are guaranteed to be together, and in increasing order, in the C standard). Even the types are the same (in C; not in C++).

Comment: @TimČas, thanks.  that actually solves the problem evaluating as equal. but don't know why it is written like that earlier `4+ '0' != 4`

Comment: @wildpointerxx As a matter of fact, `4+'0'==4` is *never* true (not to be mixed with `'4'`, i.e. `48` if using ASCII). That's because `'0'` cannot be 0 (since that's reserved for a string terminator), and thus `'1'` cannot be 1, etc ... (up to `'4'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the array `s` is passed to `process`.
each set of characters is converted to hex using `strtol` and stored in `buf`.
`buf[3]` is the fourth set of characters converted to hex, not the fourth character in the `s` array. In the example `buf[3]` is 18, 0x12. `s[3]` is '0'.
the fourth set of characters is the length of the message excluding the first four bytes. Not sure what is the significance of the first three bytes. Since the length byte does not include these first four bytes, four is added.
For the example array to pass the test, it needs to be `"04 02 56 00"` the last `00` indicates there are no more bytes to follow. The original `"04 02 56 12"` indicates there should be 18 sets characters for 18 more bytes to follow. 0x12 == 18.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it make sense that last byte is errorcode bytes that is 00 all the time while sending. You clarified my doubt, thanks a lot. I changed the buffer as "04 02 56 00" still this isn't printing I'm sending the data. Seems I'm missing something? may its due to the size of buf is 256. However you gave me the correct hint, I can identify further :)

Comment: all the information I added in my question nothing more.